# Raspbian GUI does not come back when I plug the HDMI to TV again

Tags: raspbian, gui

Happy new Year all !

When I power on my Raspberry 4 and have a HDMI cable connected to a TV set, all works fine.
Then I unplug the HDMI cable, work some days using SSH, all ok.
Some day I need the GUI again, so I plug the HDMI cable into the TV.
Unfortunately, nothing comes up - TV displays "no signal".

OpSys is :

```
pi@R4:~ $ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
```

Architecture is :

```
pi@R4:~ $ uname -a
Linux R4 5.10.103-v7l+ #1529 SMP Tue Mar 8 12:24:00 GMT 2022 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I read some logs :

```
pi@R4:~ $ sudo cat /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log
[+0.62s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log
[+0.62s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Waiting for ready signal from X server :0
[+1.24s] DEBUG: Process 11835 exited with return value 1
[+1.24s] DEBUG: XServer 0: X server stopped
[+1.24s] DEBUG: Releasing VT 7
[+1.24s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Removing X server authority /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+1.24s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Display server stopped
[+1.24s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping display server, no sessions require it
```

Some more :

```
pi@R4:~ $ sudo cat /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log
X.Org X Server 1.20.4
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
     (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
     (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sun Jan  1 11:54:52 2023
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) no screens found (EE) 
(EE)
```

And last one :

```
pi@R4:~ $ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[1188290.067] 
X.Org X Server 1.20.4
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[1188290.659] (EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
```

Well, here is when I need your wise opinions !

How can I restart the GUI using SSH ?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reinitialize HDMI without rebooting the RPi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40679/how-to-reinitialize-hdmi-without-rebooting-the-rpi)

Comment: Yes, Joel, thanks a lot